# Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, webrtc

I want to integrate webrtc in my react-native application ,Installed the package for react-native [react-native-webrtc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webrtc).Finished all the steps mentioned in the documentation ,But im getting error message

> Could not get unknown property 'mergeResourcesProvider' for object of type 
>         com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl.
>   What will be the reason for the error.[image: terminal view while run "react-native run-android"]

Answer (score 0):

react-native-webrtc Documentation is bit complicated.
From react-native versions .60 and above linking is not required,Linking happens automatically.
Just do `npm install react-native-webrtc`